# AOD measure from MODIS satellite images

Tags: qgis, modis, satellite

I need to use the MODIS Terra images, in particular the daily data that contains information about Aerosol Optical Depth. What do i have to do is to obtain the value of AOD in some precise point(in my case are ground monitor stations) and then average this values to obtain monthly data at each monitor stations.
Right now i'm using QGIS to open the image as raster layer, the problem is that when i try to open it, there are lot of layers that are opened at the same time. My question is if some of you have experience with MODIS data, and in particular if you know a better way to open and manipulate the MODIS images.

Comment: You probably want to have a script that would get a list of coordinates and MODIS tiles as input and output a table of values. This is a programming question then.

Answer (score 0):

The files you downloaded are hdf files. You need to convert them to .tif or csv file to do further analysis. Here is an R programming code you can refer to: https://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/408239_f2705d3333e940b293e8dc52a1b353a8.html

You can also modify the code and save files as .csv one by one.